# Pig split and join

Tags: apache-pig

I have a requirement to propagate field values from one row to another given type of record
for example my raw input is

```
1,firefox,p  
1,,q
1,,r
1,,s
2,ie,p
2,,s
3,chrome,p
3,,r
3,,s
4,netscape,p
```

the desired result

```
1,firefox,p  
1,firefox,q
1,firefox,r
1,firefox,s
2,ie,p
2,ie,s
3,chrome,p
3,chrome,r
3,chrome,s
4,netscape,p
```

I tried

```
A = LOAD 'file1.txt' using PigStorage(',') AS (id:int,browser:chararray,type:chararray);
SPLIT A INTO B IF (type =='p'), C IF (type!='p' );
joined =  JOIN B BY id FULL, C BY id;
joinedFields = FOREACH joined GENERATE  B::id,  B::type, B::browser, C::id, C::type;
dump joinedFields;
```

the result I got was

```
(,,,1,p  )
(,,,1,q)
(,,,1,r)
(,,,1,s)
(2,p,ie,2,s)
(3,p,chrome,3,r)
(3,p,chrome,3,s)
(4,p,netscape,,)
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIG is not exactly SQL, it is built with data flows, MapReduce and groups in mind (joins are also there). You can get the result using a GROUP BY, FILTER nested in the FOREACH and FLATTEN.

```
inpt = LOAD 'file1.txt' using PigStorage(',') AS (id:int,browser:chararray,type:chararray);
grp = GROUP inpt BY id;
Result = FOREACH grp {
    P = FILTER inpt BY type == 'p'; -- leave the record that contain p for the id
    PL = LIMIT P 1; -- make sure there is just one
    GENERATE FLATTEN(inpt.(id,type)), FLATTEN(PL.browser); -- convert bags produced by group by back to rows
};
```

Comment: Great, Thank you so much, you are right I will have to come out of the SQL mindset.

Comment: Think of it as a script, you can define multiple operation in step by step fashion that gradually augment and change the data and in many cases it is in the RAM. As example see calculation of mean, variance and standard deviation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593527/finding-mean-using-pig-or-hadoop/12618935#12618935

Comment: It was a great help alexeipab, I appreciate your time. It makes a lot of sense the way you did it.